# Association between two asymmetric matrices

Tags: regression, correlation, modeling, distance, similarities

I have two matrices which elements are distances, created from an anisotropic cost analysis algorithm, between sites/populations.

```
           A      B      C
         _                _
    A   |  0     DBA    DCA |
        |                  |
    B   | DAB     0     DCB |
        |                  |
    C   | DAC     DBC     0 |
```

However, the matrices are not symmetric in that the distance from A to B is different from the distance from B to A, or according to the above matrix D<sub>BA</sub> $\ne$ D<sub>AB</sub>

I know I [could use Mantel's test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34513/can-the-mantel-test-be-extended-to-asymmetric-matrices), although it has been heavily [criticised](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0651) and its performance has never been assessed on asymmetric matrices. I thought about using Generalised Dissimilarity Modelling but I have only found examples with symmetric examples.

I would like to know:

1)  Is Generalised Dissimilarity Modelling appropriate in my case?

and in case it is not,

2) Are other methods available to relate two asymmetric distance matrices?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I tried to improve the post, I apologise for the poor quality it had.

Comment: @whuber Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what your question is.  Could you describe how, if at all, this distance matrix was obtained from *data* and state what you are trying to discover from those data?